# Can a mind smith's materialized weapon be of large size?

Tags: weapons, equipment, pathfinder-2e, archetype, oversized-weapons

Would materializing a large-sized axe - for a giant instinct barbarian to use - be legal? For reference the [mind smith dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3862) says that:

> The overall shape and design of your mind weapon can be of your choosing

So a player of mine was wondering: is size included as a "shape and design" choice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The Mind Weapon Can Be Any Size

Mind Smith Dedication has no limitations or references to the mind weapon's size beyond this, just that it has one of the basic weapon statistics mentioned in the feat regardless of its shape and design.

So a [sprite](https://2e.aonprd.com/Ancestries.aspx?ID=39) mind smith could create a Tiny weapon for themselves or your barbarian player could create their Large weapon for their class feature. Creating a Gargantuan weapon would be interesting, but as only the mind smith can carry, hold, or wield the weapon it would be of limited use.